mongodb - nested objects over DBRef
In my MongoDB database I have among other things this three documents:
Document MessageUserConnection:
@Document(collection = "MessageUserConnection")
public @Data class MessageUserConnection {
   @Id
   private String id;
   @DBRef
   private User userCreatedMessage;
   @DBRef
   private User userReceivedMessage;
   private DateTime sortDate;
   @DBRef
   private Message message;
   ...
}

Document Message:
 @Document(collection = "Message")
 public @Data class Message {
   @Id
   private String id;
   @DBRef
   private MessageGroup messageGroup;
   ...
}

Document MessageGroup:
 @Document(collection = "MessageGroup")
 public @Data class MessageGroup {
   @Id
   private String id;
   private String name;
   ...
}

I will get all MessageUserConnections where MessageGroup is not null.
I have tried this one but it does not work:
db.MessageUserConnection.count({ "message" : { DBRef("messageGroup") :  {$ne:null} } } )

I would need a hint how to do this - thx!

Add a tag for the language this is in. Looks like Java. Also, the collection in the definition is "MessageGroup" but in the query it's "messageGroup" - lowercase 'm' instead of uppercase 'M'. Not sure if it's meaningful to refer to field messageGroup with DBRef in the query. And as a mongo query, I would assume that doing "message.messageGroup": {$ne: null} is enough.

This returns null because message and messageGroup are referenced by DBRef. The programming language is JAva but I would only needed how to do it in mongodb
